# animateCamera android not working when returning back to activity

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I am struggling with animateCamera method of the Android Google Maps API, what is happening is that it only runs once. When I come back to activity after some time its not working at all. I don't know why its not working as its working very first time when i open the activity but after that its not working at all, i debug the code and also check that if any error is thrown or not but no errors are catched. Even animateCamera method call is smoothly running but map is not getting animated to position after returning to activity again.

```
public class MapsActivity extends Activity {

    private static GoogleMap mGoogleMap = null;
    private static final String TAG = "MapsActivity";
    private Button mBtnStartRide, mBtnPauseRide, mBtnStopRide = null;
    private static TextView mTxtLatLong, mTxtTimer, mTxtTotalSize,
            mTxtSpeed = null;
    private static PolylineOptions mRectLine = null;
    // Storing the directions returned by the direcction api
    private static ArrayList<LatLng> mDirectionsPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    private SharedPreferences mPreferences = null;
    private MyBroadcastReceiver receiver = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        receiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
        mPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Preferences.PREFERENCES,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        mTxtLatLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLatLong);
        mTxtTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTimer);
        mTxtTotalSize = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDirectionsSize);
        mTxtSpeed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSpeed);

        mBtnStartRide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_start_ride);
        mBtnPauseRide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_pause_ride);
        mBtnStopRide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_stop_ride);

        mBtnStartRide.setOnClickListener(btnStartRideClickListener);
        mBtnPauseRide.setOnClickListener(btnPauseRideClickListener);
        mBtnStopRide.setOnClickListener(btnStopRideClickListener);

        initilizeMap();
    }

    /**
     * Start Ride Button Click Listener
     */
    private OnClickListener btnStartRideClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mPreferences.getBoolean(Preferences.IS_RIDE_PAUSE, false)) {
                if (RidingTimerService.getInstance() != null) {
                    RidingTimerService.getInstance().reStartRide();
                }
            } else {
                startService(new Intent(MapsActivity.this,
                        RidingTimerService.class));
            }

            mPreferences.edit()
                    .putBoolean(Preferences.IS_RIDE_STOPPED, false)
                    .commit();

            mBtnStartRide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mBtnPauseRide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mBtnStopRide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };

    /**
     * Start Ride Button Click Listener
     */
    private OnClickListener btnPauseRideClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RidingTimerService.getInstance().pauseRide();
            mPreferences.edit().putBoolean(Preferences.IS_RIDE_PAUSE, true)
                    .commit();
            mBtnStartRide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mBtnPauseRide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mBtnStopRide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };

    /**
     * Stop Ride Button Click Listener
     */
    private OnClickListener btnStopRideClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopService(new Intent(MapsActivity.this,
                    RidingTimerService.class));
            mPreferences.edit().remove(Preferences.IS_RIDE_PAUSE).commit();
            mPreferences.edit()
                    .putBoolean(Preferences.IS_RIDE_STOPPED, true).commit();
            mDirectionsPoints.clear();
            mBtnStartRide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mBtnPauseRide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mBtnStopRide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
                Constants.BROADCAST_INTENT));
        initilizeMap();

        if (mPreferences.getBoolean(Preferences.IS_RIDE_STOPPED, false)) {
            // Show start button and gone Pause & Stop both
            mBtnStartRide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mBtnPauseRide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mBtnStopRide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (mPreferences
                .getBoolean(Preferences.IS_RIDE_PAUSE, false)) {
            mBtnStartRide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mBtnPauseRide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mBtnStopRide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mBtnStartRide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mBtnPauseRide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mBtnStopRide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        setAllText();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    /**
     * Function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (mGoogleMap == null) {
            mGoogleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();
            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (mGoogleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
                mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
                mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
                mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

                mRectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(6).color(Color.BLUE);
            }
        } else {
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

            mRectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(6).color(Color.BLUE);
            animateCameraTo(mDirectionsPoints.get(0).latitude,
                    mDirectionsPoints.get(0).longitude);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handler which handle the timer of ride
     */
    public static Handler mCountDownHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            Log.i(TAG, msg.getData().getString("time"));
            mTxtTimer.setText("Timer - " + msg.getData().getString("time"));
        };
    };

    /**
     * @author Scorpion
     * 
     */
    private class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            mDirectionsPoints.add(new LatLng(intent.getExtras().getDouble(
                    Preferences.LATITUDE), intent.getExtras().getDouble(
                    Preferences.LONGITUDE)));

            setAllText();

            if (!mDirectionsPoints.isEmpty() && mDirectionsPoints.size() == 1) {
                mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(mDirectionsPoints.get(0)).anchor(0.8f, 1.0f)
                        .title("Your Location"));
            }

            animateCameraTo(
                    intent.getExtras().getDouble(Preferences.LATITUDE),
                    intent.getExtras().getDouble(Preferences.LONGITUDE));
        }

    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public void setAllText() {
        mTxtLatLong.setText("Lat - "
                + mPreferences.getString(Preferences.LATITUDE, "0.0")
                + ", Lng - "
                + mPreferences.getString(Preferences.LONGITUDE, "0.0"));

        mTxtSpeed.setText("Speed - "
                + mPreferences.getString(Preferences.SPEED, "0.0"));

        mTxtTotalSize.setText("Distance - "
                + mPreferences.getString(Preferences.DISTANCE, "0.0"));
    }

    /**
     * Animate to position on Google Maps
     * 
     * @param lat
     * @param lng
     */
    private void animateCameraTo(final double lat, final double lng) {
        // Saving the points in a polyline
        for (int i = 0; i < mDirectionsPoints.size(); i++) {
            // Elevation array
            mRectLine.add(mDirectionsPoints.get(i));
        }

        // Drawing the path on the map
        mGoogleMap.addPolyline(mRectLine);

        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(lat, lng), 17);
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
    }
}
```

Also tried this :-

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                new LatLng(17.385044, 78.486671)).zoom(12).build();

mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

What i wish is whenever user come back to this activity again, he should be able to see the path and location markers as well. I am storing all the lat long so that is not an issue for me, but things are not working with animateCamera and markers both right now. Using Google Maps v2 first time so not sure what exactly the problem is. Look forward to get some quick help or tips on it.

Comment: When i am going back to other activity and coming back to this activity it only loads the map, nothing else. But all the animateCamera and marker related code are executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

create your own class like:

```
public class MapUtil {

    public static void animateMapToPositionAndZoom(GoogleMap googleMap, LatLng position, float zoomLevel) {
        Log.i("animate map to position and zoom","Camera update on location change inclucding zoom");
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, zoomLevel);
        googleMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
    }
}
```

Override this in your activity:

```
private LatLng myLatLng;
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    if (myLatLng!= null) {
        MapUtil.animateMapToPositionAndZoom(googleMap, myLatLng, currentZoomLevel);
    }
}
```

May it help you.

Answer (score 0):

hello u can using SharedPreference then cache location. when re open app u can call "animateCamera()". importance, save location when location changed.

```
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater layoutInflater, final ViewGroup viewGroup, final Bundle bundle) {
    SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
    ...


    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // same SharedPreference
                    String model = SharedManager.getInstant(activity).getModel(Constant.CACHE_LOCATION);
                    if(model == null || model.isEmpty()){
                        return;
                    }
                    try {
                        LatLng latLng = new Gson().fromJson(model, LatLng.class);
                        animateCamera(latLng);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
    return inflate;
}

private void animateCamera(LatLng latLng) {
    final CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
            latLng).zoom(15).build();
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition), new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // todo something
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }
    });
}
```